# Having trouble using .isupper()

Tags: python, function, passwords

My program is a password strength simulator and whenever I enter a password, it *always* outputs a score of 1.

```
def upper_case():
    points = int(0)
    limit = 3
    for each in pword:
        if each.isupper():
            points = points + 1
        if points > limit:
            points = limit
        else:
            points = points + 0
        return points

pword = raw_input("ENTER: ")
upper_case()

points = 0
points += upper_case()

print points
```

Comment: You return points from within the for loop, so it always returns after the first character.

Comment: Unindent your ``return points`` by one level of indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `points` too early, because you indented it too far. Remove the indent:

```
def upper_case():
    points = int(0)
    limit = 3
    for each in pword:
        if each.isupper():
            points = points + 1
        if points > limit:
            points = limit
        else:
            points = points + 0
    return points
```

You can simplify this to:

```
def upper_case(pword):
    return min((sum(1 for each in pword if each.isupper()), 3))
```

where I changed the function to take an argument instead of using a global.

Comment: @USER1 If you paid attention to your last identical question several perfectly good password scoring solutions were presented to you including how to properly iterate, calculate a value and return it.